# Javascript Websocket Passing Code to Eval

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have a javascript object that I am passing through a websocket as raw text to a client. This raw text (for now) is directly passed into an eval statement when received. The issue is, for some reason, Javascript keeps manipulating the data before passing it to the event handler. I am at wits end.

The object that is being passed across the websocket is:

```
var obj = {
    evaluate:function(str) {
        digit = parseInt(str,10);
        if(isNaN(digit)) {
            log.write("Invalid input: "+str);
        } else {
            log.write(this.spigot(digit));
        }
    },
    spigot:function(digit) {
        len = Math.floor(10*digit/3)+1;
        A = new Array(len);

        for(var i=0;i<len;i++) A[i]=2;
        var finalDigit = 0;
        var nines = 0;
        var predigit = 0;

        for(i=1;i<digit+1;i++) {
            q = 0;
            for(j=len;j>0;j--) {
                x = 10*A[j-1] + q*j;
                x = Math.floor(x)
                A[j-1] = x % ((2*j)-1);
                A[j-1] = Math.floor(A[j-1]);
                q = x / ((2*j) -1);
                q = Math.floor(q);
            }

            A[0] = Math.floor(q%10);
            q = Math.floor(q/10);

            if(q==9) {
                nines++;
            } else if (q==10) {
                finalDigit = predigit+1;
                for(j=0;j<nines;j++) {
                    finalDigit = 0;
                }
                predigit=0;
                nines=0;
            } else {
                finalDigit = predigit;
                predigit=q;
                for(j=0;j<nines;j++) {
                    finalDigit = 9;
                }
                nines=0;
            }
        }
        return finalDigit;
    }
}
```

The client receives the message whole (I checked using both Chrome's developer tools and Firebug). However when I get the message in the following event handler:

```
function socketMessage(e) {
    log.write(e.data); //a log function I have written
}
```

e.data contains:

```
obj = {
    evaluate:function(str) {
        digit = parseInt(str,10);
        if(isNaN(digit)) {
            log.write('Invalid input: '+str);
        } else {
            log.write(this.spigot(digit));
        }
    },
    spigot:function(digit) {
        len = Math.floor(10*digit/3)+1;
        A = new Array(len);

        for(var i=0;i<len;i++) A[i]=2;
        var finalDigit = 0;
        var nines = 0;
        var predigit = 0;

        for(i=1;i<digit+1;i++) {
            q = 0;
            for(j=len;j>0;j--) {
                x = 10*A[j-1] + q*j;
                x = Math.floor(x)
                A[j-1] = x %((MISSING)(2*j)-1);
                A[j-1] = Math.floor(A[j-1]);
                q = x / ((2*j) -1);
                q = Math.floor(q);
            }

            A[0] = Math.floor(q%)(MISSING);
            q = Math.floor(q/10);

            if(q==9) {
                nines++;
            } else if (q==10) {
                finalDigit = predigit+1;
                for(j=0;j<nines;j++) {
                    finalDigit = 0;
                }
                predigit=0;
                nines=0;
            } else {
                finalDigit = predigit;
                predigit=q;
                for(j=0;j<nines;j++) {
                    finalDigit = 9;
                }
                nines=0;
            }
        }
        return finalDigit;
    }
}
```

Note how the code has been mutated. There are random `(MISSING)` strings added throughout it and several of the equations have been truncated.

Why is this happening?

**EDIT 1:**

After playing around for a while, I have noticed it happens after the `%` symbol regardless of its placement... So my question is, why significance does the `%` operator have here that is causing the event listener to slaughter the content of my code?

**EDIT 2:**

It would appear `%` is being interpreted as an escape character before being passed to my callback function. I've tried using `%25` before sending it across the socket but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%` character is being interpreted as an escape character by Javascript. The `(MISSING)` text you see added is Javascript's way of telling you the escape character wasn't followed by a two digit escape code. The easiest way around this problem is to define a function `mod(a,b)` that accomplishes the same thing as modulus. I.E.:

```
....},
mod:function(a,b) {
    return (a/b-Math.floor(a/b))*b;
}
```

Then when you need to use the modulus operator, simply call

```
Math.floor(this.mod(q,10));
```